# Why does services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson() throws exception using .Net5 core

Tags: c#, nuget-package, .net-5

I have a problem when the following code executes line services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson() It throws this exception, if the line is removed the service executes fine it appears.

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionInvokerFactory
> Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionInvokerFactory':
> No constructor for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerProvider' can be
> instantiated using services from the service container and default values.) (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.IActionInvokerProvider Lifetime:
> Transient ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerProvider':
> No constructor for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerProvider' can be
> instantiated using services from the service container and default values.) (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionResultExecutor`1
> [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.VirtualFileResult] Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.VirtualFileResultExecutor':
> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment
> ' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.VirtualFileResultExecutor'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.MvcRouteHandler
> Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.MvcRouteHandler':
> No constructor for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerProvider'
> can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.MvcAttributeRouteHandler
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.MvcAttributeRouteHandler':
> No constructor for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerProvider'
> can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values.)

I'm running under .Net5 and have the latest Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package installed. Any ideas on why services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson() throws this error?

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(); 
            services.AddHostedService<Service>();
        }).UseSerilog();
}
```

Packages installed:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Client
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices
NSwag.ApiDescription.Client
Serilog.AspNetCore
Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile
System.ServiceModel.Http
System.ServiceModel.Primitives
```

Comment: what happens if you just call `services.AddControllers();` by itself?

Comment: `ActionInvokerFactory` has been registered as a service, but not one of it's dependencies? (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ActionInvokerFactory.cs#L16) Maybe no `IActionInvokerProvider` services? That's an AggregateException, are there any other attached errors?

Comment: Thanks guys, I posted the entire exception above. If I remove the line, the service runs. Maybe it's not needed. If I run services.AddControllers(); I still get an exception error. I'm new to the .Net Core world and need Json support in my service, so I'm hoping to figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I don't use it, do I still have access to using Json package functions like  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType()? I guess what exactly does using the services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson() provide exactly. In WCF framework, I would just add the Newtonsoft.Json package and be done, but in Core it's not that easy I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with the Newtonsoft extension.

You need to import the ASP.NET Core framework to use controllers:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
```

Then use this extension method:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        // ...
    });
```

You are missing the ASP.NET Core runtimes, so it has no idea how to handle controllers.

What I would highly suggest you do (if you want controllers) is start over. When choosing your project type, choose "ASP.NET Core Website", then choose "Web API" as the type of website.

That will give you everything you need to run controllers.

Comment: Thanks Andy that makes sense. I'm developing a simple SOAP client service though and not a Web API using the .Net Core. The service is meant to communicate w/ a SOAP client to exchange messages in a background task. I need the Json support for creating Rest packets and serialization. In the past w/ WCF .Net Framework, I've just used the Newtonsoft.Json pkg and it's worked well, but I think in Core I can't use that pkg can I? If that still works in core then I could just get rid of using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package and not use controllers at all. What do you think?

Comment: @Wildview -- if you are using SOAP, then you'd use WCF. There are packages that work with WCF for .NETCore. Controllers are strictly for RESTful endpoints, not SOAP communications. You can get more information on how to use WCF in .NET Core here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: @Wildview -- this also may be interesting to you: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/custom-asp-net-core-middleware-example/